# Update a variable outside a loop from inside the loop

Tags: java, for-loop

Trying to create a method to return the first number below "n" which can be entirely divided by both the first and second divisor. Currently my program is returning the default value of "answer" being 0, I want the value which is calculated within the loop to be translated outside the loop to be returned. Yes I am a beginner :(

```
static int highestNumberBelowNDivisibleByTwoNumbers(int firstDivisor, int secondDivisor, int n) {
    int multipliedDivisors = firstDivisor * secondDivisor;
    int answer = 0;
    int remainder = 0;
    for (int i = n; i <= 1; i--) {
        remainder = multipliedDivisors / i;
        if (remainder == 0){
            answer = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return answer;      
}
```

Comment: `/` does not calculate the remainder.

Comment: multiple people already wrote good responses, but also wanted to check if your code is doing what you are asking.  I see that your question is asking about the "first number below N which can be divided by two numbers" but your code seems to be looking for something else... your code appears to be looking for first below N that can be divided into the multiple of the two divisors - i am not good at math so i don't know if that equals the same thing, but maybe try being more direct with your logic and it will simplify how the code gets written.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description of:

> Trying to create a method to return the first number below "n" which
> can be entirely divided by both the first and second divisor.

Try something more like below with the [% operator](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/modulo-or-remainder-operator-in-java/) (remainder/modulo):

```
static int highestNumberBelowNDivisibleByTwoNumbers(int firstDivisor, int secondDivisor, int n) {
    while (n>0) {
        if ((n % firstDivisor == 0) && (n % secondDivisor == 0)) {
            return n;
        }
        n--;
    }
    return -1; // no answer found      
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help dude, didn't realise that you could implement 2 return functions either. Much love <3

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
for (int i = n; i <= 1; i--) {
    remainder = multipliedDivisors / i;
    if (remainder == 0){
        answer = i;
        break;
    }
```

Decreases the counter from `n` down to 1. HOWEVER, your `answer` is not updated UNLESS remainder equals to zero. If that condition is never met, the default value of `n` will be returned (which is zero).

The problem?  `remainder = multipliedDivisors / i` when will `remainder` be zero?
Because of this assignment, `int multipliedDivisors = firstDivisor * secondDivisor;`, only if one of the "divisor" variables is zero.

Redo your logic.